Unable to connect to mongoDB cluster using the program but no problem in connecting with mongoDB compass
Whenever I start my nodejs server, I get this error: "MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted."
Although I have added my IP address and also made the option to allow access from anywhere.
Below is my code to connect to the MongoDB database.

var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.json());

mongoose
     .connect("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.lby7zh8.mongodb.net/myDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0")
     .then(() => console.log( 'Database Connected' ))
     .catch(err => console.log( err ));

    app.listen(3003)

A fun fact is I can connect to the cluster using a MongoDB compass.
Please help me through I have tried all the way to solve using chatGPT, and Gemini and am still stuck in this problem for a week

Have you tried this MongoDB Atlas -> NetworkAccess -> Edit -> Allow Any ?Have you tried useNewUrlParser: true & useUnifiedTopology: true inside mongoose.connect() after url?

yes, but still having problems with the database connection.

Does your network has Firewall?Sometime it also causes this issue.Even using VPN also causes this issue.

Well, I was able to connect to the database a week ago and I haven't used any VPN or Firewall. So, I don't think they might be the issue.
